# How do I tell if an array includes the exact values in another array to include duplicates?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
a1 = [1,4,4,4,5,6]
a2 = [4,4,4]
```

I am trying to determine if `a1` has exactly three 4s like `a2`.

I tried to use subset but it seems to exclude the duplicate values.

```
require 'set'
a1 = Set.new [1,4,4,4,5,6]
=> #<Set: {1, 4, 5, 6}> 
a2 = Set.new [4,4,4]
=> #<Set: {4}>
a2.subset?(a1)
=> true
```

This doesn't work because, when it creates the set, it ignores all duplicates.

The same goes for:

```
(a1 & a2) == a1
```

and:

```
(a2 & a1) == a2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `each_cons` to break `a1` into multiple chunks (i.e. `[1,4,4]`, `[4,4,4]`, `[4,4,5]`, `[4,5,6]`). Then you could see if any of those chunks matches `a2`.

```
a1 = [1,4,4,4,5,6]
a2 = [4,4,4]

a1.each_cons(3).include?(a2)
# => true

a1 = [1,4,5,6,4,4]
a1.each_cons(3).include?(a2)
# => false
```

Comment: This is great. I thought this was the more flexible of the responses since it also allowed me to compare arrays such as [4,5,6] as long as the array is sorted first.

Answer (score 1):

```
>> a1 = [1,4,4,4,5,6]
>> a2 = [4,4,4]
>> a1.count(4) == 3 # => true
>> a1.count(4) == a2.count(4) # => true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run [`Enumerable#find_all`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all) on an array, it will return an array of all found elements.

For this particular problem, as falsetru answered, [`Enumerable#count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) is much easier and more readable.

*Note: That will also return true if both arrays have 0 of an element:*

```
def same_amounts?(ar1, ar2, ele)
  ar1.count(ele) == ar2.count(ele)
end

a1 = [1,4,4,4,5,6]
a2 = [4,4,4]
puts same_amounts?(a1,a2,4)   #true
```